# Notify change in calculated property

Tags: c#, wpf, notify

There have been similar questions like this on this site but I have not found an answer that really works, so I post it again.

```
public MyClass
{

   public person Person1 {get; set;}

   public person Person2 {get; set;}

  CalculatedProperty 
   { 
     get
     { return Person1.Salary + (Person2.Salary/2) ; }
   }

}

public class Person
{
  public double Salary
    { get; set;}
}
```

I want to be able to notify changes in `CalculatedProperty` whenever `Person1.Salary` and/or `Person2.Salary` changes.

I have tried adding `OnPropertyChanged("CalculatedProperty")` on the setters of `Person1` and `Person2` but it does not work (and I understand why), but can't find a way to notify changes. Please help =)

(Is there a way to use an `ObjectDataProvider` for this?... Been trying that too...)

Comment: What do you mean by notify?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `Person` to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` too, then register to the two properties you have. Once `PropertyChanged` is invoked with `Salary` on either of them, invoke `PropertyChanged` on `CalculatedProperty`

```
void PersonPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.PropertyName == "Salary")
        OnPropertyChanged("CalculatedProperty");
}
```

Just remember to unregister when person is changed.

**UPDATE:**

As Jim said, your setter should look something like this:

```
private Person _person;
public Person Person
{
    get { return _person; }
    set
    {
        if (Equals(value, _person)) return;

        if (_person != null)
            _person.PropertyChanged -= PersonPropertyChanged;

        _person = value;

        if(_person != null)
            _person.PropertyChanged += PersonPropertyChanged;

        OnPropertyChanged("Person");
    }
}
```

Comment: Salary and CalculatedProperty are NOT in the same class.  Did you test this?

Comment: let `MyClass` subscribe to the OnChange properties of the `Person` classes.

Comment: @Blam, I know, that's the whole point. You register to `Person`'s `PropertyChanged` _at_ `MyClass`, and listen to changes. When `Salary` is changed on either of them, you invoke `PropertyChanged` on `CalculatedProperty`.

Comment: Please post complete code.  Just how is MyClass going to receive a property changed event from Person.Salary?

Comment: @CKII You are missing a key part, that is subscribing to the child class' `PropertyChanged`. `person.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(person_PropertyChanged);`

Comment: this works. thanks. I also have another related problem... Same as above but instead of calculating from Person1 and Person2 the CalculatedProperty takes values from a collection as in ObservableCollection<Person> . How do I modify this solution?  I tried the same thing on the collection but it didn't work....

Comment: @bayedbest, register to each `Person`'s `PropertyChanged` before you add it to the collection, the rest should be the same.

Answer (score 2):

Give CLII the check but this is a complete example

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace NotifyBubble
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property. 
        // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName 
        // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument. 
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
            Person = new Person();
            Person.Salary = 100;
        }
        void PersonPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == "Salary")
                NotifyPropertyChanged("CalculatedProperty");
        }
        public Double CalculatedProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return Person.Salary / 2;
            }
        }
        private Person _person;
        public Person Person
        {
            get { return _person; }
            set
            {
                if (Equals(value, _person)) return;

                if (_person != null)
                    _person.PropertyChanged -= PersonPropertyChanged;

                _person = value;

                if (_person != null)
                    _person.PropertyChanged += PersonPropertyChanged;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Person");
            }
        }
    }
    public class Person: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property. 
        // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName 
        // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument. 
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        private double salary = 0;
        public double Salary
        { 
            get { return salary; }
            set
            {
                if (salary == value) return;
                salary = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Salary");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to correctly raise the `PropertyChanged` of `CalculatedProperty` you have to "observe" (i.e. be subscribed to the corresponding `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event):

1. `Person1` and `Person2` properties of `MyClass`. Since they have public setters their instance could be changed causing CalculatedProperty change as well (for example, `sut.Person1 = new Person { Salary = 120 };`).
2. Property `Salary` for each object of type `Person` that is the instance of `Person1` or `Person2` property.

To avoid writing a boilerplate code for p.1 and p.2 I would suggest using [DependenciesTracking](https://github.com/ademchenko/DependenciesTracker) lib:

```
 public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private static readonly IDependenciesMap<MyClass> _dependenciesMap =
            new DependenciesMap<MyClass>()
                .AddDependency(i => i.CalculatedProperty, i => (i.Person1?.Salary ?? 0.0) + (i.Person2?.Salary ?? 0.0) / 2,
                    i => i.Person1.Salary, i => i.Person2.Salary);

        private Person? _person1;
        private Person? _person2;
        private double _calculatedProperty;

        public Person? Person1
        {
            get => _person1;
            set
            {
                if (Equals(value, _person1)) return;
                _person1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public Person? Person2
        {
            get => _person2;
            set
            {
                if (Equals(value, _person2)) return;
                _person2 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public double CalculatedProperty
        {
            get => _calculatedProperty;
            private set
            {
                if (value.Equals(_calculatedProperty)) return;
                _calculatedProperty = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public MyClass()
        {
            _dependenciesMap.StartTracking(this);
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private double _salary;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
            => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        public double Salary
        {
            get => _salary;
            set
            {
                if (value.Equals(_salary)) return;
                _salary = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Tests_SO_18445556
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test_SO_18445556()
        {
            var sut = new MyClass();
            Assert.That(sut.CalculatedProperty, Is.EqualTo(0.0));

            sut.Person1 = new Person { Salary = 120 };
            Assert.That(sut.CalculatedProperty, Is.EqualTo(120));

            sut.Person2 = new Person { Salary = 60 };
            Assert.That(sut.CalculatedProperty, Is.EqualTo(150));

            sut.Person1.Salary = 20;
            Assert.That(sut.CalculatedProperty, Is.EqualTo(50));

            sut.Person2.Salary = 100;
            Assert.That(sut.CalculatedProperty, Is.EqualTo(70));

            sut.Person1 = null;
            Assert.That(sut.CalculatedProperty, Is.EqualTo(50));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just for the record, this is how I implemented the same problem but in a collection (using a different example)

```
public class Fields : ObservableCollection<Field>
{
    protected override event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    void FieldPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "IsSelected")
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedItemsCount"); 
        }
    }

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, Field item)
    {
    if (item != null)
            item.PropertyChanged -= FieldPropertyChanged;

        base.InsertItem(index, item);

        if (item != null)
            item.PropertyChanged += FieldPropertyChanged;
    }

    protected override void ClearItems()
    {
        foreach (Field field in this)
        {
            field.PropertyChanged -= FieldPropertyChanged;
        }
        base.ClearItems();
    }

    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        if (this[index] != null)
            this[index].PropertyChanged -= FieldPropertyChanged;

        base.RemoveItem(index);
    }

    private int selectedItemsCount;

    public int SelectedItemsCount
    {
        //This can be more efficient, not have to count everytime
        get
        {
            selectedItemsCount = 0;

            foreach (Field field in this)
            {
                if (field.IsSelected)
                    selectedItemsCount++;
            }

            return selectedItemsCount;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the solution contains many issues and cannot be considered as an example of production-ready code. For example, adding/removing items to the collection doesn't cause SelectedItemsCount changed event which is obviously wrong. Also, in case the item is added as "SetItem":  fields[1] = new Field { IsSelected = true }; the subscription to the item will not happen and the code fields[1].IsSelected = false; will not cause raising of the SelectedItemsCount event.

Comment: Also, if the collection contains two references to a single item:  var fields = new Fields            { singleItem, singleItem }; then removing the first item fields.RemoveAt(1); will loose all subscriptions to singleItem and the code fields[0].IsSelected = false; will not cause the SelectedItemsCount event which is also wrong behaviour.